# Laravel templates, that shows default data every time in any page

Tags: php, templates, laravel, laravel-4

I have many different pages (like feed, users e.t.c). And on every page I have right block, that show some default information (latest news, top users and some other).

This right block not depends on main content of page, but it need some logic (fetch some latest news, fetch top users and other). I don't want to write logic in every action of controllers to provide data. I want to write it once anywhere, and view need to get it itself. How can I do it in Laravel 4?

P.S. My right block view including by @include statement from main template of application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [**view composers**](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#view-composers). It let's you do something every time a specific view gets rendered.

```
View::composer('name-of-the-right-block-view', function($view){
    // ... fetch information ...
    $view->with('news', $news);
    $view->with('topUsers', $topUsers);
    // etc...
});
```

You can basically put this everywhere. An appropriate place would be `filters.php` file.